# Four Season Porch Addition/ Garage Renovation

Tags: porch

My front entryway is falling apart and my garage is too small to use. In an ideal world, I'd love to turn the garage into a second living room and connect it to the house with a four season porch that would wrap around the entire front of the garage.
From these pictures, does this seem possible? We are concerned about all the different roof lines in the existing buildings. I’m also concerned because the front door to the house is higher than the door on the entryway—would it look really dumb to connect it with the ground-level garage?

https://imgur.com/MZ1d7VD

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEFPg.jpg)https://imgur.com/Yz88LcY

[image]

Comment: Hire a dumpster, throw out the junk, and magically you can fit a car in it - if you don't let more junk accumulate. Unless your "car" is an RV or something.

Comment: The garage is 14 by 20. Our Subaru Outback doesn't fit. It was built for a very different era.

Comment: If you can't fit a 15.9 foot car in a 20 foot garage, it's not the garage's fault. Looking back 7 years I don't see an Outback longer than 191 inches.

Comment: Ok, yes, technically, a car can fit. But we don't need the garage and haven't parked in it since buying the home. It would be more valuable as living space, which is why I'm asking the question about adding a porch to the front to connect it to the house as a single building.